# OWASP AntiSamy are replacing line breaks to espaces (JAVA)

Tags: java, owasp, antisamy

I'm using OWASP AntiSamy in a JAVA project but everytime I try call the method getCleanHTML() with a string that contains \n character, the method are replacing for a espace " ".
I'm already tried to change the rules in XML file, but it still happening.
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already fix the issue inserting the line

> `<directive name="preserveSpace" value="true" />`

in configuration file

Comment: If that works, go ahead and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Do this same work for 'antisamy-tinymce-1.4.4.xml' policy. I am adding it to true. It is still replacing new lines and spaces.